# WPF VBnet comboBox dataGrid retrieve value

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, wpf-controls

**Edit : Succeed thanks to user's comment, see below :**

First time posting on StackOverflow. I hope I did it well.

**Context** :
I'm not a professionnal programmer. I use coding for automating my job. I mainly use VBA. It is why I used VB.NET and not C#. I need to use WPF for the graphical interface, not Winforms.

I have a DataGrid which contains a *ComboBox*. I need to get the selected value of the ComboBox.

Everything I tried to achieve has failed despite the help of tons of web research and deep conversations with our fellow ChatGPT.

I tried to do MVVM but failed it. I want to avoid using it.

I apologize in advance for the code syntax you are about to see. Remain seated.

My problem is that the result of `comboBox = TryCast(cell.Content, ComboBox)` is `Nothing` which means I will never get `cellValue = item.Type(comboBox.SelectedItem)`.

Here is what I have done :

XAML part :

```
<DataGrid Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyleAssistantDevis}" Name ="dataGridInvestigations" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Height="535" Width="401" Margin="275,303,0,0" 
          FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"
          Foreground="Black"
          BorderBrush="white" BorderThickness="1"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectionMode="Single" 
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="34"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <!-- Définition de la hauteur du header -->
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unite" 
                            Binding="{Binding Unite}" 
                            Width="60" 
                            CanUserSort="False"/>
        <!-- Define DataGridTemplateColumn for ComboBox -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" 
                                Width="260" 
                                CanUserSort="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxDataGrid" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Type}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Type}"
                              Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyleAssistantDevis}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Profondeur" 
                            Binding="{Binding Profondeur}" 
                            Width="79" 
                            CanUserSort="False"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then, in the code behind :

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property Unite As String
    Public Property Type As String()
    'Public Property Type As List(Of String)
    Public Property Profondeur As String
End Class

Class MainWindow
    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim items As New ObservableCollection(Of Item)()
        items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Type = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")"}, .Profondeur = ""})
        items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Type = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")"},  .Profondeur = ""})
        dataGridInvestigations.ItemsSource = items
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonClickRedactionDevis(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim investigations(18, 3) As String
        Dim NbRow As Integer
        Dim NbColumn As Integer
        Dim cellValue As String

        Dim comboBox As ComboBox
        Dim cell As DataGridCell

        cellValue = ""

        For NbRow = 1 To 18
            ' Obtenir l'objet de données de la ligne actuelle :
            Dim item As Assistant_Devis.Item = CType(dataGridInvestigations.Items(NbRow  - 1), Assistant_Devis.Item)

            For NbColumn = 1 To 3

                Select Case NbColumn 
                    Case 1
                        cellValue = item.Unite.ToString()
                    Case 2
                        'cell = dataGridInvestigations(NbRow , NbColumn )
                        dataGridInvestigations.CurrentCell = New DataGridCellInfo(dataGridInvestigations.Items(NbRow), dataGridInvestigations.Columns(NbColumn ))
                        dataGridInvestigations.UpdateLayout()
                        cell = dataGridInvestigations.Columns(NbColumn-1).GetCellContent(dataGridInvestigations.Items(NbRow- 1)).Parent
                        comboBox = TryCast(cell.Content, ComboBox)
                        If comboBox IsNot Nothing Then
                            cellValue = item.Type(comboBox.SelectedItem)
                        Else
                            cellValue = ""
                        End If
                    Case 3
                        cellValue = item.Profondeur.ToString()
                End Select

                investigations(NbRow, NbColumn) = cellValue
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Edit** :
First, I need to thank user246821 for his comments that led me to finding the answer.
It is true that C# is way more documented than VB.NET. But I disagree with user246821 on ChatGPT's usefulness. For a non-professionnal and noobie programmer like myself, LLMs are extremely powerful, allowing us to get on the horse. Doesn't make you a rider though.
LLMs are better on massive data. So I asked it to find the solution in C#, and then, write it in VB.NET.
Here is the solution of my problem (check the ComboBox in WPF & VB.NET) :

**XAML part :**

```
<DataGrid Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyleAssistantDevis}" 
          Name ="dataGridInvestigations" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Height="535" Width="401" Margin="275,303,0,0" 
          FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"
          Foreground="Black"
          BorderBrush="white" BorderThickness="1"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectionMode="Single" 
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="34"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <!-- Définition de la hauteur du header -->
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unite" 
                            Binding="{Binding Unite}" 
                            Width="60" 
                            CanUserSort="False"/>
        <!-- Define DataGridTemplateColumn for ComboBox -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" 
                                Width="260" 
                                CanUserSort="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxDataGrid" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding TypeOptions}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding TypeSelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyleAssistantDevis}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Profondeur" 
                            Binding="{Binding Profondeur}" 
                            Width="79" 
                            CanUserSort="False"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**VB.NET part:**

```
Class MainWindow

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Items = New ObservableCollection(Of Item)()
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})
        Items.Add(New Item() With {.Unite = "", .Profondeur = ""})

        DataContext = Me

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonClickRedactionDevis(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim investigations(18, 3) As String
        Dim NbLignes As Integer

        Dim Unite As String
        Dim typeSelectedValue As String
        Dim Profondeur As String

        typeSelectedValue = ""

        For NbLignes = 1 To 18
            'Récupération des propriétés dans Item :
            Dim firstItem As Item
            firstItem = DirectCast(dataGridInvestigations.Items(NbLignes - 1), Item)
            'Récupération Unité :
            Unite = firstItem.Unite
            'Récupération Type :
            typeSelectedValue = firstItem.TypeSelectedItem
            'Récupération Profondeur :
            Profondeur = firstItem.Profondeur

            'Enregistrement :
            investigations(NbLignes, 1) = Unite
            investigations(NbLignes, 2) = typeSelectedValue
            investigations(NbLignes, 3) = Profondeur
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Item
    Public Property Unite As String
    Public Property TypeOptions As ObservableCollection(Of String)
    Public Property TypeSelectedItem As String
    Public Property Profondeur As String

    Public Sub New()
        TypeOptions = New ObservableCollection(Of String)() From {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: _I'm not a professionnal programmer. I use coding for automating my job. I mainly use VBA. It is why i used VBnet and not C#. I need to use WPF for the graphical interface, not Winforms_: The issue seems to be that you've chosen to use _VB.NET_ with _WPF_.  It seems that while you took into account that your _VBA_ experience may give you a _jumpstart_ with _VB.NET_ you failed to take into account the lack of resources available on the internet for _VB.NET_. When one adds _WPF_ into the mix, there are even fewer resources.  I recommend that you switch to using _C#_ with _WPF_.

Comment: _WPF_ has quite a learning curve for many people and an approach that works with _Windows Forms_ doesn't work with _WPF_ - they aren't the same. _WPF_ relies heavily on [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-8.0).

Comment: _ChatGPT_ hasn't evolved enough yet to really be useful for computer programming. If you need to rely on it, put your project aside and try again in 10 years.

Comment: Thank you user246821 ! Your comment help me to find the solution. I edited the post in case people had the same issue i faced.

Comment: I attempted to test your code to see the results, however, code for `ComboBoxStyleAssistantDevis` and `DataGridStyleAssistantDevis` seems to be missing. Also, you should enable [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

Comment: Answers shouldn't be posted in the OP, they should be added as another post.

Comment: Since you seem to be interested in providing something that may be useful to future readers, you may consider detailing the process that you used to generate the code with a level of detail similar to a tutorial.